# Connect USB Thermal Xprinter to Lan Network on Windows 10

Tags: networking, printer, lan

I have a setup with a computer and 4 thermal usb printers. I want to see the printers on the lab network already setup. With this; I can send print order to any printer on the network.

I have tried using usb to lan adapter to connect the usb printer to the network. But the printer cannot be seen on the network.

Is there a way I can connect these usb printers to the network without having computers on all the stations where the printers are?

Comment: You should be able to share a USB printer.

Comment: @Ramhound OP stated that he doesn't want to have a computer near each printer, this clearly excludes sharing a printer.

Comment: We don't know which kind of USB-ethernet adapter you've used, but there are small cheap printservers which are made specifically for this task.

Comment: I interpret a LAN <-> USB adapter as not being a good USB Printer Server. Have you tried that?

Comment: @mashuptwice - Unfortunately since they are USB printers they have to be connected to a PC. If they had their own network port they could be located anywhere

Comment: @Ramhound I am aware of that, but are you aware of the existence of USB print servers?

Comment: @mashuptwice - No

Comment: @mashuptwice I tried  **USB 3.0 To LAN Gigabit Ethernet Network Adapter**

Comment: @John what's the best approach to have the usb printer on the network please?

Comment: Try a USB Print Server like HP.

Answer (score 2):

You can always share the printer from one of the PCs on the network.

On the assumption that the printer runs a PDL (a Printer Description Language, such as Esc/P, ZPL, PCL5/6) you should be able to connect the printer with a USB printserver (a USB to ethernet converter). These are available from many manufacturers and work well - as long as the printer has a PDL. Check the documentation for your printer to find out whether it uses a PDL or not.

It's different if you are using a host-based printer, which relies on the Windows graphics engine to convert the page into dots on the paper. These printers are also called GDI, LIDL, PCL3 etc. For those printers, printservers only work with specific, supported printers. Most suppliers have a "printer compatibility list". If your printer is not listed you must assume it will not work.

Comment: There is one Computer on the network, the printer drivers have been installed on this computer. The Printer is Thermal Printer, XPrinter 80mm.

Comment: That printer supports ESC/POS, so a printserver should work. What model is your printserver?